# while sending mail giving error It is being used by another process.Please Try after sometime in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

1. I'm creating one file and sending that file through mail, while
   sending  Mail I'm getting this error, can you suggest what to send
   mails?
2. kindly tell me where to add code to stop coming warning of "it is
   bieng userd by another process"

   protected void btnMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
           Response.Clear();

   3. FileStream fStream = File.Create(strPath); at this line its jumping to catch block

      Response.Clear();

      try
          {
          if (Session["Projectname"] != null && Session["Projectname"].ToString() != string.Empty)
              {

      ```
          string Projname = Session["Projectname"].ToString();
          System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
          System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
          design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

          string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString();
          string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc";

          LblNoteMsg.Text = strPath;

          if (File.Exists(strPath))
          {
              File.Delete(strPath);
          }

          FileStream fStream = File.Create(strPath);
          fStream.Close();
          fStream.Dispose();

          StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strPath);
          sWriter.Write(strBuilder);
          sWriter.Close();
          sWriter.Dispose();
          Response.Clear();

          DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
          int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
          DateTime dats = DateTime.Now.AddDays(delta);
          //this week
          DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
          string MonDate = monday.ToShortDateString();
          DateTime sat = monday.AddDays(5);
          string SatDate = sat.ToShortDateString();

          StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/WeeklyMail.txt"));
          string body = r.ReadToEnd();

          MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
          string MailId = txtMailId.Text;

          foreach (string ss in MailId.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
              {
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss) == false)
                  {
                  Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ss));
                  }
              }

          Msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("support@sunlightit.com"));


          body = body.Replace("<%MonDate%>", MonDate);
          body = body.Replace("<%SatDate%>", SatDate);

          Msg.Subject = "Weekly status Report of " + Projname + "," + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "";
          Msg.Body = body;

          Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
          Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(strPath));
          SmtpClient MailServer = new SmtpClient();
          try
              {
              MailServer.Send(Msg);
              string reply = (Msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess).ToString();

              if (reply == "OnSuccess")
                  {
                  txtMailId.Text = "";
                  tblMail.Visible = false;
                  lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                  lblMsg.Text = "Mail has send succesfully";
                  }
              else
                  {
                  lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                  lblMsg.Text = "Mail delivery unsuccessfull";
                  }

              }
          catch (Exception ex)
              {
              Console.WriteLine(ex);

              if (ex.InnerException != null)
                  {
                  Console.WriteLine("InnerException is: {0}", ex.InnerException);
                  }
              }

          }
      else
          {
          Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
          }
      }
      ```

      catch (Exception)
          {
          ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('It is being used by another process.Please Try after sometime ');", true);
          }

      }

from this line its going to catch block .file is not creating
   FileStream fStream = File.Create(strPath);

Comment: Does Temp folder used by another code piece also?

Comment: no ..its not used by another code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your code, you don't need to do the calls to .dispose() as this is what the using block is for, so you could have:

```
using (var fStream = File.Create(strPath).Close())
            {
                 // these can go - (arguable you dont even need to do the close above, 
                 // but it's there for completeness's sake)
                 //fStream.Close();
                 //fStream.Dispose();
            }
            using(StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strPath))
            {
                sWriter.Write(strBuilder);
                sWriter.Close();
                //sWriter.Dispose(); - this can go too
                Response.Clear();
            }
```

Furthermore, you should probably use a similar approach to the bit where you use the StreamReader.

Also - strPath will end up hanging around on the file system (is this desirable?)

If you're merely wanting to ensure unique file names you could just use a Path.GetRandomFilename() ([see this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx))

Finally, I'd look into pulling some of this (esp the "unique file name" bit) into extension methods or testable helper objects.

HTH!

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the directory?
string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\Temp\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc";

if(Directory.Exists("...\Temp"))
{

}

Comment: no , im not checking , wat to write in this block

if(Directory.Exists("...\Temp")) {
....................

}

Comment: if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Temp")))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp"),"WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                //...
            }    
        }

Answer (score 0):

complete guess - but I suspect you're running into a process maintaining a file lock that hasn't disposed from previous calls (i.e the fileStream is opened on create on the first time around, leaving a lock floating about and then on subsequent calls trying to create the file again)

If it was me: I'd change this bit to use File.WriteAllLines() (which creates the file/ overwrites the existing file, writes, closes and disposes all in one hit)

Check : [File.WriteAllLines on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx)

Good luck!

**OR**

Even better - why create files at all?  If you're only using them to attach to the mail, why don't you just write the contents into a memorystream and base the attachment around that stream (after you've rewound it).

[Here's a link to the attachment CTor you'll need on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws(v=vs.110).aspx)

Code example:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = null;
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            sw.Write("contents here");
            sw.Flush();
        }

        ms.Position = 0;

        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "FileNameHere.txt");
    }

    var msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    {
        Body = "body text here",
        Subject = "some subject"
    };
    msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

PS - I note from your code that you're not deleting the file after sending anywhere - might want to consider that.

Comment: i tried with deleting also , not worked . file stream is not clearing. so in this line

  FileStream fStream = File.Create(strPath);
                fStream.Close();

im getting error

Comment: In that case then, I'd definitely go to my 2nd example and create the attachment based upon a memory stream (so you don't go anywhere near the file system).  Further, you want to make sure you're restarting your w3wp (IISReset / touch the web config) to make sure any processes that are hanging around are torn down.

Comment: Final comment/thing to attempt:  wrap up calling streams and readers in a "using" block rather than calling dispose / close etc.  using(var fs = File.Create("").Close()){}